# How To Pass Current Date For BlackOut Date?

Tags: wpf, xaml, date

I want to set end date as current date for black out date

i am getting current date in text block

by importing  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" in Window tag...

my source code is as follows:

```
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
       <!--==================================================================Binding Datetime.Now in TextBlock=========================================-->
       <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now},StringFormat='{}{0:dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss}'}">Now Date</TextBlock>-->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now},StringFormat='{}{0:MM.dd.yyyy}'}"/>
        <Calendar Name="Calender2">
            <Calendar.BlackoutDates >
                <CalendarDateRange Start="01.01.0001" End="HERE I want To Pass Current Date"/>
            </Calendar.BlackoutDates> 
        </Calendar> 
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I dont want to use any code behind like C#.NET OR VB.NET

I did vb.net Through Code :

Private Sub Calender_Control_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded Dim cdr As New CalendarDateRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)) Calender2.BlackoutDates.Add(cdr) End Sub

But By XAML is better.....

Thank You Dream Coder Can You Tell Me If To Pass The Day before like all dates are black till yesterday....

Thanx In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `End` to `{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}`

```
<CalendarDateRange Start="01.01.0001" End="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"/>
```

Comment: I did vb.net Through Code :

Private Sub Calender_Control_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded Dim cdr As New CalendarDateRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)) Calender2.BlackoutDates.Add(cdr) End Sub

But By XAML is better.....

Thank You dkozl Can You Tell Me If To Pass The Day before like all dates are black till yesterday....

Comment: You cannot do that in XAML only. You can create static property in your `Window` that will return date you needd and set `End` to something like `{x:Static local:MyWindow.MyProperty}` or do it in code

Answer (score 0):

a binding can be set only on the dependency property of the dependency object. where End property is neither. please remove the binding and just use `{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}` it will work.